# any way autometically add no is table

Tags: sql, sql-server

these are tables and coding.

```
create table student
(
s_id varchar(10) unique,
s_name varchar(50),
s_report varchar(50),
)

create table student_contact
(
stid int identity primary key,
stcellphone varchar(50) unique,
s_id varchar(10),
foreign key(s_id) references student(s_id)
)

create table test
(
t_id int identity primary key,
t_marks int,
)

create table st_test
(
stt_id int identity primary key,
s_id varchar(10),
t_id int,
foreign key(s_id) references student(s_id),
foreign key(t_id) references test(t_id)
)


alter view [join]
as
select s1.s_name,s2.stcellphone,s4.t_marks,s1.s_report
from
student as s1
inner join
student_contact as s2
ON s1.s_id=s2.s_id
inner join
st_test s3
ON s1.s_id=s3.s_id
inner join
test as s4
ON s4.t_id=s3.t_id

alter procedure marks
@st_id varchar(10)='',
@name varchar(50)='',
@mobile varchar(50)='',
@marks int=''
as
begin
    if(@marks < 3)
    begin
    insert into student values(@st_id,@name,'You are enrolled for 6 months')
    insert into test values(@marks)
    insert into student_contact values(@mobile,@st_id)
    select * from [join] where s_name =@name
    end
end
```

this the coding which i have created i have created a procedure to insert data now i want that in "st_test" table there is 2 column names are (s_id,t_id) which are references to student and test table now the problem is i have created a view in which these table are join and this view is already used in procedure the problem is in procedure is that i want that when i fill all parameter i will see the inserted table according to condition.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to convey here. Can you try to reword your question and break up your sentence into two or three?

Comment: Can you split that last long sentence to 2 or 3 to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
declare @id int
insert into test values(@marks)
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into st_test values(@st_id,@id)
insert into student_contact values(@mobile,@st_id)
select * from [join] where s_name =@name
```

I'd also recommend using @id in your last select statement instead of the s_name as you know it should be unique.

Comment: @Mufasil -- np, glad I could help